# Get country name from google maps in php

Tags: php, google-maps

I have user Ip address. i want country name of that user. I don't want to use geoIp(plugin) so is there any way to get country name from google maps without JS support(send country name through ajax is not option) in php ?

Answer (score 0):

Without JS yes you can be able,but still you need to use geo-plugin. You can use one from this site http://www.geoplugin.com/

```
<?php

$ip = "41.164.194.81";
$geo     = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$ip"));
$country = $geo["geoplugin_countryName"];
// $city    = $geo["geoplugin_city"];  if you need the city as well


echo $country;

?>
```

**Results :**

South Africa

Comment: Don't want to use any geo plugin. can it possible with google maps?

Answer (score 0):

Google API doesn't have any API related to IP reverse or IP location (as far as I know of)

You can use other free website if you want to.

You can use https://freegeoip.net/json/78.194.1.99, it's free and the limit is set to 10000 calls / hours.

Code:

```
<?php

   $ip = '78.194.1.99';
   $data = @json_decode(file_get_contents('https://freegeoip.net/json/' . $ip));
   $country = $data->country_name;
```

JSON Result:

```
{
"ip": "78.194.1.99",
"country_code": "FR",
"country_name": "France",
"region_code": "IDF",
"region_name": "Île-de-France",
"city": "Paris",
"zip_code": "75009",
"time_zone": "Europe/Paris",
"latitude": 48.8718,
"longitude": 2.3399,
"metro_code": 0
}
```

By the way, why you don't want to use a geo plugin ?